# How to add map marker from lat/lng coordinates? Windows 8 phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, geolocation, maps

I have added a map to the application from the toolbox, but I'm trying to figure out how to add a marker to the map which would be triggered by the click event of a button. I know how to get the devices current location like shown below.

But how would I add to this to draw a pin/marker on the map using this location data? Is there a simple method of adding the marker using the calculated lat/lng from this code snippet?

```
Geolocator geolocator = new Geolocator();
geolocator.DesiredAccuracyInMeters = 50;

try
{
    Geoposition geoposition = await geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync(
        maximumAge: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
        timeout: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)
        );

    LatitudeTextBlock.Text = geoposition.Coordinate.Latitude.ToString("0.00");
    LongitudeTextBlock.Text = geoposition.Coordinate.Longitude.ToString("0.00");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    if ((uint)ex.HResult == 0x80004004)
    {
        // the application does not have the right capability or the location master switch is off
        StatusTextBlock.Text = "location  is disabled in phone settings.";
    }
    //else
    {
        // something else happened acquring the location
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit more work than with Windows 8:

```
        var overlay = new MapOverlay { PositionOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5), GeoCoordinate = coordinate };

        var img = new Image { Width = 56, Height = 56 };
        img.Source = new BitmapImage { UriSource = new Uri("/Assets/Icons/pin.png", UriKind.Relative) };
        img.Tag = coordinate;
        img.Tap += delegate
        {
            // handle tap
        };

        overlay.Content = img;

        var mapLayer = new MapLayer { overlay };
        map.Layers.Add(mapLayer);
```

Comment: Cool,how do I pass the coordinates from my method to this? Is it at the line `GeoCoordinate = coordinate ` so how would I pass lat and lng to this piece of code?

Comment: how do I set the lat/lng coords to the coordinate variable,as it seems it only takes one value?